# what is mean incorrect syntax near '29' in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[AITS_Delete]
    @tablename nvarchar(150),
    @username nvarchar(150),
    @criteria nvarchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
   -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
   -- interfering with SELECT statements.
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
   declare @dat nvarchar(50) = getdate();

   set @sql='update '+  @TableName + ' set mdate='+@dat+  ' where ' +@username+ '=' +@criteria
   EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
```

While executing this I get this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '29'.

Comment: You need quotes around your date and username

Comment: post the output of `Print @sql`

Comment: @juergend can u show me..how to do?

Comment: actually i am passing @username is my column name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `set` statement like this.. As @juergend mentioned you were `missing quotes` around both `@dat` and `@criteria`. Also you need to convert `@dat` to `varchar` in `dynamic sql` since it is of `date` type

```
set @sql='update '+  @TableName + ' set mdate='''+convert(varchar(50),@dat)+  '''
 where ' +@username+ '='''+@criteria+''''
```

**Hint :** Always **print** the `dynamic sql` to to debug.

Comment: why we have to give three quotes in date and @criteria

Comment: @user3252014 If you are giving three quotes then you update will look like `update tablename set mdate = 2014-12-29 and username= username` is that right

Comment: @user3252014 Dude you can use `print @sql` to check how to it look like before executing

Comment: sir,,if i use print @sql ,after executing i am not getting anything

Comment: @user3252014 make sure you pass values to all the parameters.

Comment: sir,i accepted as answer,if you dont mind,can u tell me how i can debug sql stored procedure

Comment: @user3252014 If you want to debug your Dynamic sql only way is by Printing the dynamically built sql. you cannot do a update like `update tablename set columnname = somestring ` instead it should be `update tablename set columnname = 'somestring' ` quotes is what you were missing and you can check that by printing the `@sql`

Answer (score 0):

By building dynamic sql in this way, your code is prone to quote escaping issues and Sql Injection attacks.

You can *partially* parameterize your dynamic Sql statement by passing the where filter variables to `sp_executesql`. Unfortunately, you won't be able to parameterize the table name or column name, although with some luck these will come from trusted and tested sources and be less prone to issues:

```
DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @dat DATETIME =getdate();
SET @sql = N'update ['+  @tableName + ']' + 
           N' set mdate= @dat where [' + @username + N'] = @criteria';

EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql, 
     N'@dat DATETIME,
       @criteria nvarchar(150)',
     @dat = @dat,
     @criteria = @criteria;
```

Other:

- Use `[..]` around the column and table names to protect against column names with spaces etc
- Don't convert your date to varchar unnecessarily.
- The query passed to `sp_executesql` should be unicode (hence `N''` prefix)

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6c0c2/3)